# Are Muslims more accountable for sins than non-Muslims?

Tags: sin, non-muslim, conversion

Do Muslims get more sins for doing haram acts than non-Muslims as they are aware that it's wrong and shouldn't be done?

also if someone want to revert to Islam but can't do the primary acts like praying or fasting, etc.. because of being afraid that their family might find out or other reasons should that person revert to Islam by just doing the shahada first or should they stay non-Muslim until they are fully committed to Islam?

Comment: Honestly this looks like two distinct questions which should be addressed separately (see in [our meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions)) I'd even assume that both have some answers or let's say partial answers on input on the site.